# copy CCK content (for auto translations) upon new content created tigger in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, triggers, translation, cck

what I want and need to do is upon the event that triggers when a new node is created, is first to translate it into every language enabled except the one is created and copy and even translate if possible the CCK content.

I'm doing this with triggers and it is creating and translating the content but only the title and body (non CCK)

What I want to do is copy the images that were uploaded on the original node, set the dropdowns, etc etc..
of course it wouldn't be bad to use the i18n gtranslate to translate the textboxes and textfields to the translated CCK on the new node when the event triggers :)

I'm sure this problem was solved before, but I don't know how to affect the newly created node and use it's CCK ... and how to refer to the original node from which is being translated on the php evaluation block..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [module Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), you will be able to create "actions" which is basically a callback where you can do whatever you want.
You execute those actions when an event is triggered (let's say for example when a node is created) and if a set of conditions is evaluated to true (node type, if some fields have some particular values etc).
In this action callback you can fetch the "source node", generated a new node which your translations on each field and then save a node for each language.

Comment: Which part don't you succeed to accomplish? Fetching the original node? Have you tried to create a custom rule? Examples are provided in the documentation (http://drupal.org/node/298486)

Comment: So what I figured out so far is that I have to load a node https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_xe9TQhB7n2Q/TbhAKfnhZOI/AAAAAAAAB98/sm54VBeCaZg/translate2.jpg and find the NID, but I don't know how to specify the source from which was translated from , or the new NID that was created by the action..

Comment: I'm sure there is a relation because if I go to the article tabs screen (translations) the "source" apears https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_xe9TQhB7n2Q/TbhB7YH50tI/AAAAAAAAB-E/xEtrYc8VZWs/translate3.jpg . Can you help me solve this? I'm sure many multilanguage sites have it..

Comment: here I might of found something : $node->tnid points to the source nid , so the original has nid and tnid equal :) so from there I guess I can make a ruleset and run that ruleset if the conditions are right. just tell me if I'm on the right track or if things can be done otherwise much simpler

Comment: You are one the right way but rules isn't going to do the translation for you, it's going to instanciate the nodes to create a translation for each of your languages but you still have to manage the translations. Since you have to translate something you have two options, first is not using the action translate in every language and do it directly in your code while you are translating it, second is letting rules generating the translated nodes and then re-edit the content to "do" the real translation.